# What is wrong with my File::Find::Rule->grep call?

Tags: perl, grep

I am trying to fetch the list of .cpp files that have a class "MyClass" being used in it.

Here is the snippet:

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @match_files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.cpp')->in('.')->grep("MyClass");
```

However, this is giving the following error:

```
Can't call method "grep" without a package or object reference at ./script.pl line 20.
```

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with this call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that the LHS of the last `->` operator was *not* an object. That is because the `in` method evaluates the rule and returns a list of matching files.

So you should probably swap the `grep` and the `in`:

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->name('*.cpp')->grep(qr/MyClass/)->in('.');
```

You can re-read the documentation at [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule).